# Encoding function in x86 machine code. Returns bad result

Tags: c#, assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm doing some binary x86 encoding, but it doesn't work, even if the binary numbers correspond to the right disassembled binary code.

I have written a program in C#, just for prototyping, that puts the bytes in unmanaged memory, I have created a delegate, and executed it but I always get the wrong result back - and I have got it working with simpler functions though, such as a function that returns the 4-byte number 42.

This is the function that I try to encode, rendered in C:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I compile it with GCC. The result is rendered like this in Intel-syntax:

```
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],esi
mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
add    eax,edx
pop    rbp
ret
```

Which in machine code is:

```
55
48 89 e5
89 7d fc
89 75 f8
8b 55 fc
8b 45 f8
01 d0
5d
c3
```

I put these bytes in memory, allocated using VirtualAlloc, and retrieve a delegate of this type, through Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int Add(int a, int b);
```

And when I invoke the function "add" with arguments 2 and 3 I would expect 5 as the result, but instead I get different numbers (probably addresses), like 36204020, every time I call it.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong as my assmebly is a bit rusty, but "r" registers (like rbp and rsp) aren't x64 registers? doesn't it should be "e" (like esp and ebp)?

Comment: You used the sysv abi for the code but you presumably run it on windows which uses the microsoft convention. Also that code can be a lot shorter, you forgot to enable optimizations. PS: hopefully your process is running in 64 bit mode.

Comment: Crashes like a ton of bricks when I try this.  As it should, the processor's NX (execute disable) bit stops these kind of shenanigans.  It is also completely incompatible with the x64 abi, first 4 arguments are passed through registers.

Comment: @HansPassant because you didn't pay attention to memory protection flags? :) Also it does pass arguments in registers but it's using the sysv abi which is the wrong one for windows.

Comment: Maybe it is because of the lovely snippet I copy/pasted from the question.  Why anybody would ask a question like this is quite beyond my comprehension.

Comment: So you select "CallingConvention.Cdecl", and then the gcc binary is using sysv 64b abi, those are not compatible. Either select the correct calling convention in delegate, or set gcc to produce cdecl (maybe even 32b?) object code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl
(the gcc binary expect parameters passed in edi and esi, and returns value in eax, while cdecl will put input parameters on the stack itself)

Comment: even if the coding convention was correct, shouldnt it be [rbp-0x8] and [rbp-0x12] ? (8 bytes stack used, 4 for return adress, and 4 for the bp just  pushed? )

Comment: @Tommylee2k: nope. The input values are incoming in edi and esi. [rbp-4] is NOT the upper stack frame from caller, but the temporary stack space under it to store temporary values. If the optimization would be switched on, the gcc would produce probably something like this: `mov eax,esi / add eax,edi / ret`. And rbp and return address in x64 is 2x8B, so first stack input value from caller is probably at [rbp+16]? (too lazy to verify :) )  (and -0x12 is not what you wanted... -0xC it should have been ;) )

Comment: @Ped7g: holy crap you're right, i had 2 brain farts in one, misreading Intel with AT&T Syntax (it's a move INTO memory, not from) ... ashes over my head :-)